# mapsqlparametersource vs java.util.map

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I read in spring documentation that MapSqlParameterSource is just a wrapper over Map. What is the advantage of using MapSqlParameterSource instead of Map?

```
public int countOfActorsByFirstName(String firstName) {

    String sql = "select count(*) from T_ACTOR where first_name = :first_name";

    SqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource("first_name", firstName);

    return this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, namedParameters, Integer.class);
}




public int countOfActorsByFirstName(String firstName) {

    String sql = "select count(*) from T_ACTOR where first_name = :first_name";

    Map<String, String> namedParameters = Collections.singletonMap("first_name", firstName);

    return this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, namedParameters,  Integer.class);
}
```

Comment: Currently nothing. It's legacy remains from times when there was a chance you might be using a Java version that doesn't have support for generics.

Comment: As the javadoc shows: a fluent API to populate the parameters, the possibility to specify SQL types for the parameters.

Comment: @JBNizet good point.  For completeness, an additional consideration - if you're defining a stored procedure this advantage may no longer be relevant since you specify the SQL type when defining the stored procedure - e.g. new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).declareParameters(new SqlParameter(FIRST_NAME, Types.VARCHAR)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `MapSqlParameterSource` is just a decorator of a `LinkedHashMap`, if you check the `MapSqlParameterSource`, you will see this:

```
private final Map<String, Object> values = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
```

There are not actually considerable benefits of using a map or spring provided implementation.

If you dig a little on the code, you can use `addValue`, below the code:

```
public MapSqlParameterSource addValue(String paramName, Object value) {
    Assert.notNull(paramName, "Parameter name must not be null");
    this.values.put(paramName, value);
    if (value instanceof SqlParameterValue) {
        registerSqlType(paramName, ((SqlParameterValue) value).getSqlType());
    }
    return this;
}
```

So, as you can see, `addValue` returns the same object, which you can use (if you like) to do fluent method calls, like:

```
.addValue("a", 1).addValue("b", 2)...
```

So, it's just a matter of taste to use `Map` or `MapSqlParameterSource`

Comment: A downside of using MapSqlParameterSource is the missing constructor `new MapSqlParameterSource(MapSqlParameterSource)`. I. e. you can't reuse params already set. For example, when creating a report I want to reuse the start and end date of a period for multiple statements with different additional arguments. In this case I have to use a conventional map so I can do: `new MapSqlParameterSource(periodParams).addValue("additionalParam", foobar);`